# Получение access токена в Dialogflow

Tags: python, dialogflow

можете ли вы мне помочь с получением access token для Dialogflow? Я в материалах читал, что там надо что-то пройти, но до конца не понял. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Первая ссылка в Google - [https://help.carrotquest.io/article/139]

Comment: @SergBocharov ваша ссылка некорректна.

Comment: https://help.carrotquest.io/article/139

Comment: @SergBocharov данный метод я пробовал но всё равно не понял. У меня там некоторых функций нету, например, выбрать версию api v2 и т.д

Comment: @SergBocharov спасибо большое сам разобрался!

Comment: @SergBocharov после данной настройки все равно access token не появился, лол!?